# Return array of dates and times from Calendar API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api, oauth2-playground

There is no clear, concise, and easy-to-follow example for setting up a JavaScript google calendar API call.

I found an example that I tried to use plugged my OAuth key into and it does not work.
To see the specific errors please visit [Staging Website](https://torontohomecleaning.ca/booking/) and open the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Enter an API key from the Google API Console:
  //   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
  var apiKey = 'mXMq9NAQ9EOzdgleTTy4wobx';
  // Enter the API Discovery Docs that describes the APIs you want to
  // access. In this example, we are accessing the People API, so we load
  // Discovery Doc found here: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/
  var discoveryDocs = ["https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/torontohomecleaning12@gmail.com/events"];
  // Enter a client ID for a web application from the Google API Console:
  //   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_
  // In your API Console project, add a JavaScript origin that corresponds
  //   to the domain where you will be running the script.
  var clientId = '646125501608-jtauc86qulpebg2oh49k4qglfjui82gc.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  // Enter one or more authorization scopes. Refer to the documentation for
  // the API or https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing
  // for details.
  var scopes = 'events';
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API client and auth2 library
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: apiKey,
        discoveryDocs: discoveryDocs,
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: scopes
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
  }
  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
      makeApiCall();
    } else {
      authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
      signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }
  function handleSignoutClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
  }
  // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
  function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.people.people.get({
      'resourceName': 'people/me',
      'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names'
    }).then(function(resp) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      var name = resp.result.names[0].givenName;
      p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello, '+name+'!'));
      document.getElementById('content').appendChild(p);
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" 
  onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" 
  onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

The problem: I can't find a copy and paste example, where, all I have to do swap out is the OAuthkey and clientID so that I can return an array of dates and times currently on my Google Calendar that I am the owner of.

The end goal: To be able to filter a jQuery date-picker blackout dates based on the array of dates returned.  Then, filter a drop-down menu of time slots based on what has already been booked for the day (if any times slots are available).

I can't get past this first step of getting everything talking to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using the Google People API. For the call you requested (Getting an array of dates & times currently on your google calendar) I suggest you use the Google Calendar API (instead of the People API). You can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) comprehensive quickstart. For your specific needs, you can also head over to the [list events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?apix=true) API page, where you can use the API call builder to generate the necessary Javascript code to make it work.

This is the code that it generated for the request you need to make:

```js
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for calendar.events.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      "calendarId": "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

You only need to set your API key, client ID and calendar ID to make it work. If you have any other question, please do not hesitate to reach back.

Regards.

Comment: The issue now is that an OAuth2 screen prompts the user to sign in with their Google account when that should not be necessary.  Furthermore, when I click "Authorize and load", and then close the prompt, it seemingly loads perfectly fine.  Any ideas?  I've implemented the code and plugged in my credentials on the staging site.

Comment: Alexander Dixon: In order to use the API from the client-side, you need to use the OAuth2 authentication flow (including "prompting" the user with it). What you can do instead is either to get the calendar information from the server-side using a 'service account', or fetch the data from the client-side without using Google's APIs (see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064149/accessing-a-public-calendar-using-google-api-without-requiring-a-user-to-log-in). Cheers!